# Question about index

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, transfinite-induction

Sometimes basic elements are not easy to understand. It is well known result that every perfect can be written as  pairwise disjoint  perfect sets. Assume $P\subset\Bbb R$ be  a perfect set. and let $\Bbb P$ be the set of all perfect subsets of $\Bbb R.$ Then, Let $$\mathcal P:=\{P^K_{\xi}\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\ \ \&\ \ K\in\Bbb P\}$$  be a partition of $P$ into perfect sets. I have no problem about that. My question about the indexes:

Does that mean for every $\xi<\mathfrak c$  and for every $K\in\Bbb P$ I have pair $\langle \xi, K\rangle$ index for some perfect set  such that  $P^K_{\xi}$ in $\mathcal P$? Or not. Also I know the partition can be written as $\{P_{\xi}\colon \xi<\mathfrak c\}$ but I am asking in case as in $\mathcal P$. As I said my question seems simiply but I just want to make sure I am in right path.

Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: indexing is quite arbitrary. What is your end goal?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I want to see if my understanding in case correct or not

Comment: Well, there are continuum many members of your $\Bbb P$ (confusing notation, as it stands also for the set of irrationals: $\Bbb P \cup \Bbb Q= \Bbb R$ etc). Why do you chose a partition in continuum many perfect sets of $P$? Maybe fewer suffice.. Like I said, what is the end goal?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I think you missed understood my question nut thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you gave a set of size $\mathfrak{c}$ (like your partition of $P$) you can index it by another set of size $\mathfrak{c}$ (the product of $\mathfrak{c}$ and $\Bbb P$) and we can devote each member of that partition as some (unique) $P^K_\xi$ as you did. But **why** one would is unclear, it's more common to just enumerate them as indexed by ordinals (for transfinite recursion e.g.). It could be for a bookkeeeping reason perhaps.

Comment: Hernno Brandsma, I did this partition before and yes there is a reason behind  the indexing in this way. Thank you